# Is it possible, in an R script, to read a zip file from the supplements of EsaJournals?

Tags: r, zip

Is it possible to read a zip file from this site?
Eventually I would like to extract on the fly a single 'tsv' formatted .txt file.
Using the URL in the address box of a browser starts a download process.
My code produces the error message below, is there a solution?

```
>  read_tsv(unz(description = "https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/action/downloadSupplement?doi=10.1002%2Fecy.1745&file=ecy1745-sup-0001-DataS1.zip", filename = "CLO-PLA-traits.txt"))
```

> Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection In
> addition: Warning message: In open.connection(con, "rb") :   cannot
> open zip file
> 'https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/action/downloadSupplement?doi=10.1002%2Fecy.1745&file=ecy1745-sup-0001-DataS1.zip'

Comment: is there a reason you can't `download.file()` to a temporary directory and go from there?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware of there is no possibility to directly extract and download only one file from an archive. Ben Bolker pointed to a good solution if you have the option to download a temporary file would be:

```
url <- "https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/action/downloadSupplement?doi=10.1002%2Fecy.1745&file=ecy1745-sup-0001-DataS1.zip"
temp <- tempfile()
download.file(url,temp)
data <- read.csv(unz(temp, filename = "CLO-PLA-traits.txt"), sep= '\t')
unlink(temp)
```

Glimpse on the data.frame `data`

```
psych::describe(data) %>% head(2)
              vars    n    mean     sd median trimmed     mad min  max range skew kurtosis    se
Species_name*    1 2909 1455.00 839.90   1455    1455 1077.85   1 2909  2908 0.00    -1.20 15.57
woody            2 2909    0.06   0.23      0       0    0.00   0    1     1 3.84    12.79  0.00
```